# Forbid Programming Language Bashing

Tags: discussion

In many (if not all) Questions where a Specific Programming Language is called the first thing that will be posted is a Comment " 'Insert Language Here' is the Problem/Fault/Reason".

That is in no way in any aspect constructive! As far as I know exists there no Programming Language where no Security relevant issue could occur so every Language can have a Security relevant issue and so is this comment on the "First"-comment.

Further more this will lead to a very chatty comment Section due to the Pro and Contra factions of the Programming Language.

Further more expand this to Frameworks but there is the Problem that some of them are really a Security Issue.

Is there a way to forbid that kind of comments/have a rule that forbid them

> The Reason for this Post is a recent Thread, which is one of many where I saw it. [Link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127550/is-the-undesirable-conversion-of-a-scientific-number-a-vulnerability)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, we do tend to do this, so generally where this happens the comments get deleted. That example you posted, isn't a great example however for a couple of reasons:

- this hardly ever happens on Security Stack Exchange
- this one didn't degenerate into a long comment war
- it was intended and received as a joke
- it's true*

So I think our current approach is effective and avoids the sort of problems you are anticipating. Our Be Nice rule and management of comments handle this if it does develop into an issue.

TL;dr - not currently an issue - it's handled

*joke

Comment: And, in some cases the effect in question *is* the result of the way the specific language does things. So, "it's true" can be ... true.

Comment: Another was a Wordpress Question where I was one of the guys who where not so "non-chatty". I think I just hit a higher ratio of questions with that kind of thing. (Url to the Worpress thing: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151467/wordpress-site-blog-post-replaced-with-hacked-by-sa3d-hack3d yhea it was a Very bad Question in the beginning, but the commenting about the best framework make it much worse) PS: I was not angry about the comment and I find it more a provoking joke as some language bashing ;)

Comment: @Serverfrog I was the author of that framework comment, and I would like to defend my point. I am not bashing a particular product for the sake of bashing it, but because I see the damage done by its vulnerabilities every day. I don't see why you consider it "bashing" when I point out actual flaws in the product and recommend to steer away from it.